# Palm tree leaves turning light green

Tags: houseplants

My palm tree leaves are turning light green. It’s a 20 year old plant always been indoors. What should I do.  I haven’t tried anything yet.

Comment: Please try and post  a photo

Answer (score 1):

nine times out of ten, palm issues are due to specific fertilizer requirements or soil incompatiable with watering.

Poke the soil if it's spongy it's fine if it's forms a puddle you're overwatering.

Also may be time to change containers.

Lastly what fertilizer are you using at all? A good one uses an 8-2-12 NPK rating.

Comment: Could just be 20-year old soil. Might scoop and replace without repotting.